# How to play Facebook style video using UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, avplayer

I am attempting to play video in `UICollectionview` Cell using **[ZOWVideoPlayer](https://github.com/stoncle/ZOWVideoPlayer)**. Video is playing perfectly but currently my **collectionview** is playing all visible videos. I want to play only single completely visible video. This means the current video that is not cropped by scrolling process (pixels are not off-screen, but fully visible).

I also added code to check the complete visible cell in **scrollview** delegate methods but then my **collectionview** gets stuck for 1 or 2 seconds and then moves, so please help me out.

**And Please Read question first then make Down vote.**

Here is the code for check visible cell

```
- (void)checkVisibilityOfCell:(CustomCell *)cell inScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView {
    @try {
        CGRect cellRect = [aScrollView convertRect:cell.frame toView:aScrollView.superview];
        if (cell.videoPlayer) {
            if (CGRectContainsRect(aScrollView.frame, cellRect)){
                //Play Video
            }
            else{
                //Pause Video
            }
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {

    } @finally {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code of visible cells checking for clarifying your question.

Comment: i update question please check it

Comment: _just a passer-by advice_... @Hardik, **(1)** Please add a coding language tag. Is that `Swift` (or `Obj-C`)? Someone who knows answer might not even be watching your current specified tags, but we all check for our coding language(s), right?.. **(2)** What is "Facebook style video" exactly? Improve the desired description (I ascertained you need video to play when centralised to screen or at least when scroll position does not "crop" any pixels otherwise it should auto-pause. Is that a good guess?). How are you checking position?

Comment: @Hardik, I tried to fix. Correct anything wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your method is getting called more than once. As you are only checking for players existence. Why don't you add another check for the player state? So if the player is playing, just ignore it.

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(aScrollView.frame, cellRect) && !isPlaying) {
```

isPlaying -> An enum you can add for storing player current state

Hope this make sense ;)

Comment: I think it's about video position on screen during scroll. See if the new question edit helps...

Comment: @VC.One Absolutely it is due to the position. As long as the video is fully visible on the screen, the delegate method will get called. So if we ensure that the player will call "play" method only once, we won't face the delay. As I suspect the main cause for delay is the play being called multiple time.

Comment: I don't use Swift / Obj-C (seen because Asker tagged `video`). Will the video auto-pause when a subtle scroll now makes it only partially visible? The next video in new "most visible" cell will now auto-play?. You have a potential correct answer if that's true. But that is for Asker to confirm...