# How to play a central video from the list when scrolling stops

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-streaming, tableview

I've made the iOS app **(using Swift)**, which fetches videos from the website and displays them in the list(displays videos' thumbnails to be precise).

I'm using Table View and fill out a Prototype Cell with the data from the website. It gives me a scrolling effect.

When the user clicks on the thumbnail it brings him to the page with a webView where the video can be played.

*Could you please give me a reference to videos/articles or explain based on your own experience* **how to play a central video from the list when it stops scrolling.**

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : **http://stackoverflow.com/q/38888218/2057709**. See if the answer there helps you.

Comment: It's close. Thank you @VC.One I'll try to do that in Swift
GuysI invite you to add your options. Preferably for Swift.